# Why are my \right), \right], and \right} being styled red?

Tags: katex

I'm using katex, and writing some latex, and have some equations involving `\left(` and `\right)` and whatnot. Suddenly, all of my `\right)` began being styled as red.

The classes being applied (which include `color:red` css) are:

- `span.delimsizing.Size3`
- `span.mclose.delimcenter`

but the element is also being styled as red directly, as in `<span style="color:red;">)</span>`

Is this a bug in katex?

**Update**: When I remove the following from my TeX, the issue goes away.

```
\color{blue}{\dPdt} = 
\frac{
\frac{\color{red}{\kcat} \, 
\color{blue}{[\mathrm{E_T}]}
\color{blue}{[\mathrm{S}]}}
{\color{red}{K_{m,\mathrm{S}}}} - 
\frac{\color{red}{\koff} \, \color{blue}{[\mathrm{E_T}]} \color{blue}{[\mathrm{P}]}}{\color{red}{K_{m,\mathrm{P}}}}}
{1+\frac{\color{blue}{[\mathrm{S}]}}{\color{red}{K_{m,\mathrm{S}}}} + \frac{\color{blue}{[\mathrm{P}]}}{\color{red}{K_{m,\mathrm{P}}}}}
```

Note: there are some macros above:

```
\newcommand{\kon}{k_{\mathrm{on}}}
\newcommand{\koff}{k_{\mathrm{off}}}
\newcommand{\kcat}{k_{\mathrm{cat}}}
\newcommand{\kuncat}{k_{\mathrm{uncat}}}
\newcommand{\kms}{k_{m,\mathrm{S}}}
\newcommand{\kmp}{k_{m,\mathrm{P}}}
\newcommand{\dSdt}{\frac{d[\mathrm{S}]}{dt}}
\newcommand{\dEdt}{\frac{d[\mathrm{E}]}{dt}}
\newcommand{\dESdt}{\frac{d[\mathrm{ES}]}{dt}}
\newcommand{\dPdt}{\frac{d[\mathrm{P}]}{dt}}
```

Comment: Can you give a complete example of code that causes this? Are you ever using `\color{red}`? Does this happen on the demo on katex.org?

Comment: I _am_ using \color{red} elsewhere in my notebook (I'm using jupyterlab-katex from https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers/tree/master/packages/katex-extension). Copy pasting the contents of some cells into the demo on katex.org, I'm having a hard time reproducing... If you have any guesses off the bat I'd love to hear them :)

Comment: When I remove the jupyter cell which includes the \color{red} and refresh the page, the issue goes away. I've added the offending TeX to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably what's happening here is "contamination" of the current color between KaTeX formulas, via the internally defined/updated `\current@color` macro.

Context: This macro is used to get some intended behavior like `\color{red}\right)` producing a red right parenthesis, even though it's changing the color inside a left...right scope.

This sounds like a bug that was fixed in [PR #2703](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/pull/2703), which appeared in KaTeX 0.13.0 and later.  Can you confirm that Jupyter is using KaTeX 0.12 or earlier?  (`katex.version` in the JavaScript console might tell you.)

A workaround would be to `\gdef\current@color{}` to reset the color at the end of the cell that uses `\color{red}`.

Comment: Confirmed, jupyter uses `katex.version"0.12.0"`

Comment: By the way, this bug also only happens when the `globalGroup` ia set to true. If you can set that to false, you shouldn't have this problem anymore.